# Why do I get this error in this very simple mwe?

Tags: table-of-contents, tufte, titletoc

Why do I get this error in this very simple mwe? It seems that the same error appears in the `book` class, two.

```
\documentclass[notoc]{tufte-book}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\chapter{Introduction}

\startcontents[chapters]
\printcontents[chapters]{}{1}{}

\section{Historical Overview}
\section{The CUDA Model}
\section{A Lattice Boltzmann Solver}

\addtocontents{toc}{text}

\chapter{chap3}
\section{My Overview}
\end{document}
```

Comment: I was wrong.  I will delete my earlier comment.

Comment: @StevenB.Segletes:  `\addtocontents{toc}{foo}` uses `\@writefile{toc}` which generates code in the `toc` file, which is only read by `\@starttoc` (within `\tableofcontents`) -- if one does not maliciously use `\@starttoc` in the preamble, there would be no problem with writing normal text to the `ToC`.

Comment: @ChristianHupfer That became clear seeing Ulrike's and Werner's answers.

Comment: What error do you get?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You need to insert a paragraph break before the chapter line. As \par directly is not allowed, use \endgraf:

```
\documentclass[notoc]{tufte-book}
\setcounter{secnumdepth}{3}
\setcounter{tocdepth}{3}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents
\chapter{Introduction}

\startcontents[chapters]
\printcontents[chapters]{}{1}{}

\section{Historical Overview}
\section{The CUDA Model}
\section{A Lattice Boltzmann Solver}

\addtocontents{toc}{text\endgraf}

\chapter{chap3}
\section{My Overview}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Could you please explain what is the `\endgraf` command?

Comment: `\endgraf` is an alias for `\par`, but can be used in places where `\par` leads to the `! Paragraph ended before XXX was complete.` error.

Answer (score 3):

It stems from the introduction of random text inside the `.toc` file via

```
\addtocontents{toc}{text}
```

If you wish to do so, ensure that the text is on its own by issuing a `\par` afterwards.

The following minimal example replicates the problem:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

\tableofcontents

\section{A section}

\addcontents{toc}{text}% Error
%\addtocontents{toc}{text\par}% No error

\section{Another section}

\end{document}
```

Comment: If you put a `\par` in my code, you will see that the error still appears!

Comment: @Sisabe: It doesn't in my (smaller) example. However, you could use `\addcontents{toc}{text\protect\\}`.